# SQLite and JDBC: returns UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I am running Xubuntu in VirtualBox. I installed sqlite3 which for some reason does not come bundled any more. I added sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar to my build path and run this simple code to test it.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JDBC_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:161)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:145)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:66)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:21)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at JDBC_test.main(JDBC_test.java:7)
```

I get the same error when I try to connect to an existing DB by substituting "test.db" with the full path to the file. Any ideas why?

Comment: IIRR, SQLite requires a native library to be loaded

Comment: "Our SQLiteJDBC library requires no configuration since native libraries for major OSs, including Windows, Mac OS X, Linux etc., are assembled into a single JAR (Java Archive) file." This is from Xerial. Also their sample code doesn't have any additional steps before DriverManager.getConnection.
see https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Comment: FYI, I was unable to recreate your issue on Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit with a runnable JAR that I created in Eclipse on Windows using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar. (All I did from a fresh install of Xubuntu was `sudo apt-get install default-jre`.)

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu 32-bit. I'll try the 64-bit version and report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in driver version 3.8.7 in xerial's [bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/152/387-version-linux-issue). The quick (and working) solution is to use driver version 3.8.6 until that bug will be fixed.

Update: the bug was fixed since version 3.8.10.2 (see new bug tracker on [Github](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/34)), I confirm that it works now.

Answer (score 4):

Version 3.8.11.2 works on Ubuntu 14 (I tested it on x86), it can be downloaded from: 
https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads

Comment: I think you mean 3.8.11.2 ?

Comment: @Nitred *facepalm* you are right! I'm fixing it right now