# UnsatisfiedLinkError Access is denied Java Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10, access-denied, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a java desktop application which uses sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1. On a XP machine, it works all right. I recently upgraded from Win7 to Win10.
Now the following error crops up:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\<user_account>\AppData\Local\Temp\sqlite-3.8.10.1-e8e7a431-c992-4fa1-b701-2e96ddd03362-sqlitejdbc.dll: Access is denied
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:161)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:218)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:74)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
.
.
.
```

I have tried

```
icacls "%APPDATA%\Local\Temp\" /grant <user_account>:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

which completes successfully but still no use. Btw, the account i'm logged in is an admin account.

Any ref. at the right direction will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Why is there a Sqlite DLL in your TEMP directory?

Comment: it uses the sqlite jdbc jar file. I guess it extracts during run-time.

Comment: Seems you are using a bad JAR version. Similar question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148541/sqlite-and-jdbc-returns-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: Guess my search term was wrong.
Thank you. I'll try and let know.

Comment: Okay that was it. It works fine with sqlite-3.8.10.2.

Answer (score -1):

I got this Error too. For my case is the program that running the jar file is not have permission to extract the dll to the temp folder. I just use Run as Administrator Everything is fine.

Comment: Now you have a security hole on your system: Any attacks against the software in question will damage not just your user account but the entire machine.